# Auto stop instance after a time limit

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'd like to stop an instance automatically after a time limit, say 1 hour.

This is for the case, the network connection get lost and I can't send a stop request.

I'd like to start instances programmatically via AWS SDK for PHP. So maybe there is a way for passing options for a time limit.

By right clicking on an instance, there is a "Create Alarm" option with a "Stop Instance" action. But there is no "running time" condition available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The really easy way would be to add a  `shutdown -h 60` to your startup script on /etc/rc.local if you're using linux.

Comment: Nice. This could pass via User Data too.
For other users, the shutdown command needs to run with with `sudo`.